# Put logic behind generated LinqToSql fields

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In a database I use throughout several projects, there is a field that should actually be a boolean but is for reasons nobody can explain to me a field duplicated over two tables where one time it is a char ('Y'/'N') and one time an int (1/0).
When I generate a datacontext with LinqToSql the fields off course gets these datatypes.
It would be nice if I don't have to drag this stupid choice of datatype throughout the rest of my application. Is there a way to give the generated classes a little bit of logic that just return me

```
return this.equals('Y');
and
return this==1;
```

Preferably without having to make an EXTRA field in my partial class.
It would be a solution to give the generated field a totally different name that can only be accessed through the partial class and then generate the extra field with the original name with my custom logic in the partial class.
I don't know how to alter the accesibility level in my generated class though..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-clicking and selecting "Properties" of the property in the LINQ-To-Sql designer will allow you to alter the visibility. Next, you can provide an implementation with your desired logic in your partial class.

Comment: Heh, I missed the visibilty part +1 for alertness :)

Comment: By making the property use the original private property, Linq to Sql is not able to use this property in it's generated sql queries though. That's a downer :(

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property to translate the char value into a boolean, you can use this to get and set the char value based on your boolean input.

This can be done in a partial class.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but it was the invisible part that i was looking for :)